Possible to use-package 'foo defer :config (foo-autoloaded-macro)?
I noticed (use-package polymode :defer t :config (define-hostmode …)) would load polymode on startup instead of deferring, which seems to be because define-hostmode is an autoloaded macro
;;;###autoload
(defmacro define-hostmode

so I moved my calls to (define-hostmode into a file of its own and did :config (require 'a-file-of-its-own) instead, but is there a way to "eval-after-load" which works with such macros? It seems a bit arbitrary to have to have a separate file if I call an autoloaded macro in use-package :config.
(This also feels like something a sufficiently smart linter would tell me about.)
